# Generalized eigenvalues of overdetermined systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I have a system of equations that can be written as

${(\bf{A}} + \lambda{\bf{B}}){\bf{x}} = 0$

Where ${\bf{A}}$ and ${\bf{B}}$ are $n \times m$, integer matrices. I know that there are several values of $\lambda$ that correspond with a nontrivial $x$ and that solve the system. What can I do to find $\lambda$ in general?

My first idea was to just do Gaussian Elimination on the matrix ${\bf{C}} ={(\bf{A}} + \lambda{\bf{B}})$, essentially making it square. However, it seems like I am throwing away information if I do that.

Comment: I think you should use the so called QZ algorithm

Comment: You can consider the related system $(A + \lambda B)^T(A + \lambda B)x = 0$

Comment: @Surb, I have not heard of that before, but [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition#Generalized_Schur_decomposition) suggests that it is only possible on square matrices.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I understand that system would be square, but could you elaborate on how to go from there?

Comment: Note that (perhaps surprisingly) $(A + \lambda B)^T(A + \lambda B)x = 0 \implies (A + \lambda B)x = 0$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I don't immediately see why that's the case. Assuming it's true, I should then be able to just do $det({(\bf{A}} + \lambda{\bf{B}})^{T}{(\bf{A}} + \lambda{\bf{B}}))=0$, correct?

Comment: Yes, I think that should work.  I'll post a proof as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim:** For a fixed $A,B, \lambda$, 
$$
(A + \lambda B)x = 0 \iff (A + \lambda B)^T(A + \lambda B)x = 0
$$
**Proof:** $\implies$ holds trivially.  To prove the other implication, note that
$$
(A + \lambda B)^T(A + \lambda B)x = 0 \implies\\
x^T(A + \lambda B)^T(A + \lambda B)x = 0 \implies\\
[(A + \lambda B)x]^T[(A + \lambda B)x] = 0 \implies\\
\|(A + \lambda B)x\|^2 = 0 \implies\\
(A + \lambda B)x = 0
$$
Thus, as you indicate, it is sufficient to find the $\lambda$ such that
$$
\det[(A + \lambda B)^T(A + \lambda B)] = 0
$$

Comment: Very nice, thanks! I am going to try to program this as soon as I can. I hope the quadratic terms in the new matrix don't increase the complexity too much...

Comment: I myself am pessimistic about the performance of this approach... at the very least, this amounts to finding the roots of a degree $2n$ polynomial rather than a degree $n$ one, assuming you compute the formal determinant, which can itself be a hefty computation.  If I think of an improvement, I'll let you know.  Good luck!

Comment: I wonder if there's some sort of "completing the square" process that can be applied here.

Comment: Is there any reason why I can't just do Gaussian elimination on the resulting matrix? After that, I could just read off the values from the diagonal. I'm guessing the process of elimination would amount to the same complexity as solving the $2n$ polynomial, but at least I get to exploit the fact that my $A$ and $B$ are quite sparse.

Comment: I found [this (pretty old) article](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-026-04/S0002-9939-1970-0266418-6/S0002-9939-1970-0266418-6.pdf) on the subject, but I'm having a hard time reading it so far.

Comment: Gaussian elimination should work... I'm not sure how well that goes along with the $\lambda$ and $\lambda^2$ terms floating around.  Try it!

Comment: I hope you stille see this after a couple of days. As it turns out, I was looking at The wrong matrix earlier. Now, with the correct matrix, if I just do Gaussian elimination on it, making it square, I actually find the eigenvalues I am expecting on the diagonal. I don't understand how this could happen, since it seems like I could add any amount of equations to the system and still maintain the result as they just get eliminated. Do you have any idea what might be going on?